# Convert Spritekit Game to Android?

Tags: android, sprite-kit, libgdx, 2d, cocos2d-x

Are there any new options for converting a spritekit game to android? It seems the only options are to recode everything in Java or to use Cocos2D, LibGDX, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately ... no :{

And the cross-platform SpriteBuilder with the Apportable service that let you convert a Swift Cocos project to Android is no longer available (they got bought out by Google I believe).

SpriteBuilder is still available on GitHub but it's not active afaik and is abandoned.

So... what to do?

I would focus on iOS... you can make your game "cross platform" by converting to macOS and tvOS... This is where all of the money is in the market... Apple products...

If your goal however is cross platform, then you can look at Xamarin.forms alongside CocosSharp which will give you write once run everywhere games in C#

You also have regular Xamarin available to write gameplay code in C#, and share it across Android and SpriteKit wrappers written in C# as well.

Another thing to look at is Silver which has Swift wrappers for Android.. thus letting you port Gameplay code almost directly...

In all scenarios you will have to find another game engine for whatever Android solution you use..

IMO, developing with Swift for Apple is much easier and more fun than anything I've ever done with Android dev, even though I prefer Android devices (go figure), and since the revenue is higher it is sort of a no-brainer for starting up.

Answer (score 7):

There are no easy options for supporting Android with a SpriteKit game, but with a little bit of work and not too much difficulty you can recode your game to use Cocos2d-x.  I just completed such a project for my game.  It took me about four months working half time.  I've posted some tips here: http://doffen.org/porting-spritekit-to-cocos2d-x.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a look here: http://processing.org/
and here : http://www.ricardmarxer.com/fisica/
Fisica is a wrapper of jBox2D for Processing and is quite easy to use. There are a few tweaks for android but nothing too hard.

I did it in the opposite direction (converting my fisica-based game to SpriteKit) and it was quite easy to create regex replacement to easily migrate to swift syntax.