# Android equivalent framework to Apple SpriteKit

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, sprite-kit

I'm actually building an IOS app with a Tab Navigation.
These Tabs mainly contains lists and tables (like a business app), except one which host a SpriteKit view controller with a "mini 2D game" (Single Scene, One background image and multiple small animated images who respond to gesture).

In the future I want to be able to port my app to Android with a native solution :

- Rewriting the business part of the app in Kotlin, is Ok
- Creating UI views with lists and tables, is Ok
- Creating a 2D scene and displaying a 2D scene in a controller, fail ...

Does Android have an engine like that ?
Does somebody have an idea or one alternative to the SpriteKit/SceneKit view controller in Android ?

[EDIT]

My idea is not to convert the SpriteKit scene to display it in android, but to find a way to build the same app from scratch in android.
What would be the best way to go if I had to create a simple 2D scene (with simple animations and gesture control) and to display it in the rest of my android "business app" ?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Spritekit Game to Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680356/convert-spritekit-game-to-android)

Comment: The answer is still the same

Comment: The author writes "My idea is not to convert the SpriteKit scene to display it in android" so  this is not the duplicate as in the "Convert...." thread the exact opposite is discussed.